# Definition of unduloidal k-lobed Delaunay tori

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Recently I came across a review about constrained Willmore energy conjecture. But there are some hard understanding concepts I never heard before, such as unduloidal k-lobed Delaunay tori. So I would like to know whether this concept has a strict definition. I have searched on google but tell me nothing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://www.gang.umass.edu/

Comment: @WillJagy So the concept '2-lobed' has no definition? We can only identify the number of lobes by the plot?

Comment: you ought to give a link to the review you read. The unduloidal surfaces make me think of the non-compact constant mean curvature  examples.  This preprint says CMC surfaces are to be considered for some constrained problems. There is an entire book https://www.routledge.com/Willmore-Energy-and-Willmore-Conjecture/Toda/p/book/9781498744638

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry for that. The link of the review is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03217.pdf). I saw the concept of k-lobed tori in last 7th line on page 5.

Comment: it seems some things were defined after 2010, and Lynn Heller is in the middle of it.  One of her advisers is at U. Mass. Amherst;  https://www.differentialgeometrie.uni-hannover.de/de/heller/publications/